# Не работает swap - поменять местами минимальный и максимальный элементы

Tags: python, list, список, индексация, swap

Не могу понять, почему не работает обмен переменных.
Само задание:

> В списке все элементы различны. Поменяйте местами минимальный и
>   максимальный элемент этого списка.

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
print(' '.join([str(s) for s in a]))
```

При вводе: `1 5 4 3 2`, обмен не происходит. Помогите понять, почему?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Разбор полётов:

Выражение

```
a, b = c, d
```

выполняется в следующем порядке - сначала вычисляется слева направо всё в правой части от знака `=`, потом вычисленные значения присваиваются переменным из левой части - тоже слева направо:

1. c
2. d
3. a
4. b

Смотрим, что происходит:

1. (c): ==>  результат: `5`
2. (d): ==>  результат: `1`
3. (a): ==>

   ```
   In [48]: a.index(min(a))
   Out[48]: 0

   In [49]: a[0] = 5

   In [50]: a
   Out[50]: [5, 5, 4, 3, 2]
   ```
4. (b): ==>

   ```
   In [51]: a.index(max(a))
   Out[51]: 0

   In [52]: a[0] = 1

   In [53]: a
   Out[53]: [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
   ```

   ---

После шага `3`:

```
a == [5, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Соответственно, на четвертом шаге `a.index(max(a))` вернет `0` - первый встретившийся максимум.

Далее вы присваиваете `a[0]` вычисленный заранее (шаг `2`) минимум `1`. Вуаля - все вернулось на свои места.

---

Чтобы разрешить данный конфликт, надо сохранить индексы минимума и максимума, как это показано в [ответе @S.Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002734/211923).

---

**Интересная деталь**: ваше решение отработает правильно если в исходном списке максимальный элемент встречается до минимального:

```
In [57]: a = [4, 3, 5, 1, 2]

In [58]: a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]

In [59]: a
Out[59]: [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
1 5 4 3 2

indMax, indMin = a.index(max(a)), a.index(min(a))
a[indMax], a[indMin] = a[indMin], a[indMax]

print(a)
[5, 1, 4, 3, 2]
```